# Ubuntu Software Icon?

Tags: 16.04

I loved the new icon for the app Ubuntu Software, but suddenly the old icon(icon for the software center) has back. How can I fix this? Can I even fix it?

1.Update
When I look in the direction `/usr/share/applications`, the normal gnome-software icon is displayed, but when I moved it or opened it the panel shows the ubuntu-software-center icon:

[image]

2.Update
I followed the directory `/usr/share/ubuntu/applications`. Typed `sudo gedit *.desktop` and change the icon direction to the pictures. There I had the gnome-software icon. After logout and login, the icon has changed. That is a temporary change I think, but I'll stick with that.

Comment: The new software centre replaced the old one and uses the same name and icon to avoid confision

Comment: @Motte001 Thanks for the answer, however the new icon was better than old, I guess I'm the only one to think like that :)

Comment: Is the icon only changed, but also does it run the old SC? I definitely have another icon. @Motte, nope, the new name is "Software" instead of Software Center. Another icon, another .desktop file, another name, another command.

Comment: @JacobVlijm The new one is `gnome-software`, but it is called "Ubuntu Software". Yes, it is not exactly the same name, but very similar

Comment: The issue is that in some cases, in case of upgrades, there was a mix up with old/new versions,, mixing up of .desktop files. The .desktop file is  `gnome-software.desktop`, The *interface* name "Software" in Dutch, but apparantly language- specific. @Egrimo could you mention what is the case?

Comment: @JacobVlijm the case is, 16.04 brings gnome-software and it had a new icon with white-blue. After some updates the icon has changed into the old brown software-center icon. Currently I'm triying to find the blue-white icon, after that I'll change the icon with pHeLiOn 's answer.

Comment: @Egrimo Please include a screen grab showing what your issue is, in your question.

Comment: @Egrimo not here, still blue and white, totally updated.

Comment: @dobey http://i.hizliresim.com/goA8Q5.png as you see here the old icon is replaced with the new white icon. That's what I'm trying to change

Comment: So what does clicking on the orange icon open, exactly?

Comment: @dobey it opens the new Ubuntu Software App.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It seems to be possible to change any icon you want.

There's a link here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/03/how-to-change-an-application-icon-in-ubuntu-unity-tips/ that worked for Ubuntu 14.04, so should work for Ubuntu 16.04 in the same way.

You'll have to go find the icon you liked (should be able to download it if you can't find it on your system).

It's possible that an update to the package in the future *might* replace your changed icon if the package itself has an update to it's original icon.

Fairly unlikely though.

Comment: First we need to find what is exactly happening. Icons don't change just like that.

Comment: I was running an Ubuntu 16.04 installation at the crossover period between the old Ubuntu Software application being replaced by the new Gnome Software application. The icon changed to the Gnome Software icon in blue. After a few updates it changed back to the Ubuntu Software icon. I suspect that Egrimo was also doing the same and now prefers the Gnome Software icon that was there for a little while.

Comment: @pHeLiOn exactly, only problem is: I can't find the blue icon to change this.

Comment: This icon might be what you're after: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:GNOME_Software_icon_hicolor.svg if you download it (from firefox right-click and 'Save image as...') you'll get an .png image with a transparent background.

Comment: @pHeLiOn thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for.